# Is there a way to track a face through a live webcam and place a mask on it on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity and trying to make filter like masks (like snapchat for examples) to be put on a live recording (through a webcam) of a human face on Unity. Let me know if you need more explanation!

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.